# Adding method to List and passing anonymous parameter

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I have the following Scala code to answer question 4 (implement dropWhile on a list, which removes elements from the List prefix as long as they match a predicate) of Chapter 3 of [Functional Programming In Scala](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617290653):

```
object Chapter3 {

    sealed trait List[+A]

    case object Nil extends List[Nothing]
    case class Cons[+A](head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]

    object List {

        def apply[A](as: A*): List[A] =
            if (as.isEmpty) Nil
            else Cons(as.head, apply(as.tail: _*))

        def dropWhile[A](l: List[A], f: A => Boolean): List[A] = 
            l match {
                case Nil => sys.error("cannot drop from empty list")
                case Cons(h, t) if f(h) => dropWhile(t, f)
                case _ => l
            }

    }

    def main(args : Array[String]) {
        def smallerThanThree(i: Int): Boolean = i < 3
        println( List.dropWhile(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), smallerThanThree) )

        // How can I call this directly on the list with anonymous function like below?
        println( List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).dropWhile(i => i < 3) )
        // => Should return List(3, 4, 5) or Cons(3, Cons(4, Cons(5, Nil))).

    }
}
```

What I want to do is twofold:

1. Call `dropWhile` on the list object (`List(1,2,3,4,5).dropWhile([f: A => Boolean])`) instead of using `List.dropWhile([List[A]], [f: A => Boolean])`
2. Pass an anonymous method (`i => i < 3`), instead of defining the function `smallerThanThree` and passing this.

Now this gives the error:

> error: value dropWhile is not a member of Main.List[Int]

And the anonymous function does not work also. When I do

```
println( List.dropWhile(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), i => i < 3) )
```

it gives the error:

> error: missing parameter type

Can anyone explain if the above two points can be accomplished, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you to be able to call `dropWhile` on an instance of the *trait* `List`, that trait must declare this function. The fact that the *object* by the same name contains this function does not automatically "add" this method to the trait.

You can easily add such a function to `List` trait by changing the trait definition to:

```
 sealed trait List[+A] {
   def dropWhile(f: A => Boolean): List[A] = List.dropWhile(this, f)
 }
```

Then, your suggested code works as expected.

As for passing an anonymous function - in this case the compiler can't infer the `Int` type on its own, so you must explicitly write the type, as follows:

```
println( List.dropWhile(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (i: Int) => i < 3) )
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. To add to your answer, you can actually also have type interference on a passed anonymous function like `i => i < 3`. That can be done if the signature (and implementation) is changed as follows: `def dropWhile[A](l: List[A])(f: A => Boolean): List[A] `. Then you can change the method in the trait to: `def dropWhile(f: A => Boolean): List[A] = List.dropWhile(this)(f)`. And you don't have to specify the type anymore and can use `dropWhile` as follows: `println( List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).dropWhile(i => i < 3) )`.